# I am having trouble installing pip with python, what to do?

Tags: python, pip

I watched youtube tutorials but no information found so far that solves my problem. When I try to install pip it says:

> "uninstalling instead"

and in the program it says this:

> " NameError: name 'pip' is not defined"

I don't understand and I can't find any information regarding this error type online.

Comment: Are you on PC or a UNIX (macOS, Linux) based system?

Comment: Have you checked if the PATH environmental variable is pointing to python.exe?

Comment: Using > for formatting error gives oversight in your question.

Comment: post OS, pip and python version by updating your question. Also elaborate on how you try to install pip (code used in cmd..etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are calling pip install from within python shell which is not the correct way to execute it. pip can be called only from shell and not from within python shell.

Comment: See the link to install pip https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ . Once it is installed you can call "pip install <package-name>" from shell directly to install respective package (Do not use python shell to call pip install)